# Effervescent in mineral spirits?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I'm shooting video of paint moving in mineral spirits.  To make for a little more action, is there a household granular/solid I could add to the mineral spirits that would gently effervesce ala alka-seltzer in water?

Comment: Are you looking for something that will effervesce in water or mineral spirits?

Comment: Something that would effervesce in mineral spirits.

Answer (score 2):

A [fish-tank bubbler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B073JGFLT7) with needle valve or regulator would not only provide bubbles but be controllable and would not need to be replenished, as would chemicals.

**N.B.** However you make bubbles in mineral spirits, it would help the highly-flammable liquid to evaporate, creating a potential **explosion and fire hazard**. You might get better images with less-miscible mineral or silicone oil, with less danger.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My thought is that a bubbler uses puffs, so it would mess with the effect, and the scale of what I'm doing is very small, a petri dish of spirits, so no hazard ;)

Comment: Those using motors do make noticeable puffs, but the vibrator type, especially through a fine stone, tend to make streams... which still might not meet your needs. Dry ice might work, if you could insulate it so that it doesn't sublime too rapidly.